# Isotope.js and meteor

Tags: meteor, jquery-isotope

am using a packaged version of isotope.js inside a meteor project and i cant seem to get it to behave correctly. usually it gets called on a document ready in jquery. in meteor the equivalent is template.name.onRendered, however its seems rather flaky with isotope.

i do have three instances of it inside the meteor project but they're all called with different div id's on different pages/routes so i don't think that is the problem. the interesting thing is, if you resize the browser the cards that are used in the isotope view re-shuffle and will eventually return to the desired positions.. its really odd. any ideas ?

this is my code that triggers the isotope instance

```
Template.sell.onRendered(function(){
// ISOTOPE SETUP
$('#container').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.card',
    masonry: {
        gutter: 20
    }
}); 
})
```

Comment: I've been using Isotope this way for some time. Just a guess, but if the items are dependant on a Collection, you could try using `waitOn` in iron router if you're not already. That way the template won't be rendered until the data is available and Isotope won't be getting run prematurely (which is what I suspect is happening)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put in Meteor.defer. Because at onRenderd $("#container") will not available. So try below code

```
    Template.sell.onRendered(function(){
    // ISOTOPE SETUP
    Meteor.defer(function ({
    $('#container').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.card',
        masonry: {
            gutter: 20
        }
    }); 

})
})
```